# "I actually might have to X" vs. "I might actually have to X" vs. "I might have to actually X"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

> Even if there are four fan headers on the motherboard my computer case accommodates six fans (3x140mm, 3x120mm) so I actually might have to purchase an external fan hub.

Where should I put the word "actually" in the sentence? Should it be before or after "might", or placed before "purchase"?

Comment: It could be left out entirely...

Comment: And 'Even if there are four fan headers on the motherboard my computer case accommodates six fans ... so I ...' might be better written 'There are four fan headers on the motherboard, but as my computer case accommodates six fans, I ...'

Comment: As long as we're copyediting the example sentence, I recommend this revision: "My computer case accommodates six fans (3x140mm, 3x120mm), so I might have to purchase an external fan hub even if the motherboard I use has four fan headers."

Comment: Actually, I might have to say that this doesn't make much difference...  In spoken English, they're all fine; in written English they're all OK but somewhat redundant/informal.

Answer (score 1):

The word "actually", as used in this and similar contexts, is used to express some degree of unexpectedness or mild surprise.

For example, consider the following:

- The dinner was quite good.
- The dinner was actually quite good.

The first version simply comments on the quality of the dinner.  The second version comments on the quality of the dinner, while implying that the diner was not expecting the quality.

"The manual says the car gets 40 miles per gallon, but I actually get 35."

In your case, "actually" does not seem to be a good fit anywhere.  I'd leave it out.